# How to select/merge multiple matching result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to create a cascading set of drop-down list, country list based upon the region list.

I have created a `Dictionary<String, List<String>>` in the code behind, which includes a region, country list.

Now on region drop down selection (which is multi select able), 
I need to select the countries belonging to the particular regions(selected ones) and bind it to the country list.

I am trying this way:

```
List<string> selectedRegions = (from ListItem item in regionList.Items
                                where item.Selected
                                select item.Text).ToList();

var countryList = (selectedRegions
                          .Where(item => regionToCountry.ContainsKey(item))
                          .Select(item => new { value = regionToCountry[item] }));

countryList.DataSource = countryList.ToList(); 
countryList.DataBind();
```

The problem is country list gets the result in indexed format like : countryList[0] (contains all the country from region a)
countryList[1] from region B.

I need a merged list which I can bind to the dropdown.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Vishal

Comment: First of all, how does this compile `var countryList = ...; countryList.DataSource = countryList.ToList();`??

Comment: Sounds like you may need `.SelectMany(.....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) to flatten the `List<string>` inside the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

```
var countryList =
    regionToCountry.Where(x => selectedRegions.Contains(x.Key))
                   .SelectMany(x => x.Value)
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Beautiful, tough a little complicated for me to understand :), but worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var countryList = selectedRegions
                          .Where(item => regionToCountry.ContainsKey(item))
                          .SelectMany(item => regionToCountry[item])
                          .ToList();
```